# How to put instance into related field serializer

Tags: django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, djoser

im try to use djoser to handle JWT auth for my registration logic

My exact problem is **ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('city_name', 'New York')])": "CustomUser.native_city" must be a "City" instance.**

I also try inherit by `serializers.ModelSerializer`, but in this case I can't activate my user by activation link with uid and token

I spend a lot of time to figure out what is the problem, but everesing  was unsuccessfull

Please help solve this error

**models.py**

```py
class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, validators=[validate_email])
    native_city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('email', 'username'),
                name='unique_username_email')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())]
    )

    native_city = CitySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'native_city')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        native_city_data = validated_data.pop('native_city')
        city_instance, _ = City.objects.get_or_create(city_name=native_city_data)
        city_instance.save()
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(native_city=city_instance, **validated_data)
        user.save()
        return user



class CustomUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    native_city = CitySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'native_city')
```

Full traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /auth/users/
djangoweatherremider-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     response = get_response(request)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     raise exc
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 18, in create
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 227, in is_valid
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 429, in run_validation
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     value = self.validate(value)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djoser/serializers.py", line 71, in validate
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     user = User(**attrs)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 543, in __init__
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 266, in __set__
djangoweatherremider-web-1  |     raise ValueError(
djangoweatherremider-web-1  | ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('city_name', 'New York')])": "CustomUser.native_city" must be a "City" instance.
djangoweatherremider-web-1  | [30/Aug/2023 10:06:42] "POST /auth/users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16728
```

Comment: Share the full traceback.

Comment: Edit my question with full traceback @WillemVanOnsem